# Calling VTable function using GDB

Tags: gdb

I am trying to call a function using GDB, this function belongs to a instantiated class. I don't have debug symbols available, although I do have a pointer to the class/vtable and the offset of the function.

Is it possible to be able to call such function?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it is possible.  You can always call a function by address.  Simplest is to cast the pointer to the correct type, or a type that is "correct enough according to the ABI".  E.g.:

```
set $fun = (int (*) (void *)) 0xADDR
call $fun ("whatever")
```